# Windows Phone Background Video

Tags: c#, background, windows-phone-8.1

I was wondering if it is possible to play video as a background?
Whilst maintaining the functonality of the buttons?

[image: A simple design example]

An example of the Android version of the app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.comizzo.roadsmart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. In a Silverlight app you can set the page background as a [VideoBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/system.windows.media.videobrush%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). In a Windows Phone Runtime app put a MediaElement as the back element on your page.

Put the buttons you want on top of the video controls and they'll work fine.

```
<Grid>
    <MediaElement /> 
    <Button />  
</Grid>
```